# FTP Send package publish DotNet Framework GitLab-ci-yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to publish an aspnet mvc 5 project via ftp using GitLab CI / CD.
I configured the runner as it is at the link https://medium.com/@gabriel.faraday.barros/gitlab-ci-cd-with-net-framework-39220808b18f
I'm having difficulty in the last step, which is to take the generated publish and send it to another server via ftp, as the runner executes with powershel the lftp generates an error in the build.
can you help me?
Here is my yaml code:

```
variables:
  NUGET_PATH: 'C:\Tools\Nuget\nuget.exe'
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe'

build_job:
  stage: build
  cache:
    key: build-package
    policy: push
  script:
    - echo "*****Nuget Restore*****"
    - '& "$env:NUGET_PATH" restore'
    - echo "*****Build Solution*****"
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" /p:Configuration=Release /clp:ErrorsOnly'
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" FisioSystem.MVC\FisioSystem.MVC.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:Configuration=Release /P:PublishProfile=Publish_FisioSystems.pubxml'
    - echo "*****Install lftp*****"
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp 
    - echo "*****Upload file to ftp*****"
    - lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST; mirror -R C:/Deploy/ ./../manager --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/; quit"
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    when: always
    paths:
      - ./FisioSystem.MVC/bin/release
    expire_in: 1 week
  only:
    - master
```

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: + apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
 +                    ~~
 The '&&' token is not a valid instruction separator in this version.
     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

Comment: changed && to; and returned the following error: apt-get: The term 'apt-get' is not recognized as a cmdlet name

Comment: You have windows paths defined in yaml and linux commands with apt package manager. It seems like you mixed windows and linux configs without regard to actual os in your runner. Seems like this question is off topic.

Comment: the linux command is to illustrate what I want to do, but I don't know how I would do it with windows commands.

Comment: That should be your question then.

Answer (score 1):

If your gitlab runner is custom windows machine then [manually install](https://nwgat.ninja/lftp-for-windows/) `lftp`. Then command will be available in your pipeline.

After you installed `lftp` on runner, just remove from pipeline

```yaml
    - echo "*****Install lftp*****"
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
```

Comment: Naturally best solution to syncronize git repository using git commands. Good to hear!